# ASP.NET display list<string> in listview or gridview instead of dropdownlist (web service application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webservice-client

The below code works well only when I display the result in dropdownlist but when I try to display it in a label or listview or gridview, it refuses when i replace the dropdownlist1 with a label.
Someone can show me how to do it?

```
   TenderNotificationInfo[] noticeInfo = returnVo.tenderNotificationInfo;

            int len = noticeInfo.Length;

            List<CTendNotificationInfo> tendInfo = new List<CTendNotificationInfo>();
            List<LotInfo> lot = new List<LotInfo>();

            CTendNotificationInfo tend_curr = new CTendNotificationInfo();
            //LotInfo lot_curr = new LotInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {

                tend_curr.PENAME = noticeInfo[i].tenderRefNumber;
                tend_curr.PECODE = noticeInfo[i].tenderRefName;
                tendInfo.Add(tend_curr);

                TenderLOTInfo[] lotInfo = noticeInfo[i].tenderLOTInfo;
                int size = lotInfo.Length;

                if (size != 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                    {
                        lot.Add(new LotInfo()
                        {
                            LOTNO = lotInfo[j].tenderLotNumber,
                            LOTNAME = lotInfo[j].tenderLotName,

                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            Session.Add("tendInfo", tendInfo);
            Session.Add("lot", lot);

            //begin of displaying in DropDownList1 *****************************************************************************
            DropDownList1.DataSource = tendInfo;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DEADLINE";// TENDREFNAME";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "TENDREFNUM";
            DropDownList1.DataBind(); //end of displaying in DropDownList1 ************************************
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "refuses"?

Comment: I tried to replace the dropdownlist1 with a label but it brings some errors i think maybe it because i don't know how to use label or gridview, or listview

Comment: Please show the complete error details and the code that does not work instead of the code that you are not having trouble with.

Comment: Below are code that are not working 

ListView1.DataSource = tendInfo;
ListView1.DataBind();

And this is the error message that it returns:
"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An ItemTemplate must be defined on ListView 'ListView1'."

Comment: It looks like you have not defined a ItemTemplate on the ListView, take a look at the documentation for ListView to see how to use it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. let me take a look